# Not able to install anti-virus software after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, anti-virus

I upgraded my operating systems from WIndows 8 to Windows 10. I used F-secure version 9.32 as my anti-virus program but I'm unable to install it in Windows 10.

Windows 10 complains incompatibility issues and advices upgrading anti-virus to newer version.

I tried most of the advices [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/228689/how-to-make-old-programs-work-on-windows-10/). I tried running install-program as administrator, running in Windows 8 compatibility mode and disabling unsigned driver check. None of these options helped.

What do you think, is my only option to upgrade my F-secure to a newer version or is there a way to resolve this incompatibility issue?

Comment: You should only use software that supports Windows 10.  if your not willing to update your software use Windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 has a blinded kernel so, the only antivirus software that can really deal with kernel and offer solid protection is Windows Defender.

Comment: This is 100% false.  There are dozens of anti-virus software suites that fully support Windows 10.  I have no idea what you mean by "blinded kernel", Windows 10 uses the same NT kernel, that every other version of Windows since Windows XP has used (just a different build of it)

Comment: If you say Windows 10 is not supported by Norton, McAfee, Bitdefender, Nod32 and other then I don't need to know what your talking about to know your statement is incorrect.  So what exactly do you mean by "blinded kernel" because I was unable to find any actual source for that term before I made that comment.  Doesn't matter, I am taking your comment, as being not constructive which serves no actual constructive purpose.

Comment: You made the claim that " the only antivirus software that can really deal with kernel and offer solid protection is Windows Defender." which simply isn't true.  All those software suites offer the same integration as Windows Defender.

Comment: This is simply not true.

Comment: You are right.  Wonderful informative answer keep up the good work!